# QGIS Processing plugin: "NameError: name 'standard_library' is not defined"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, plugins

I've created a processing plugin using the "plugin builder" in QGIS 3.32. Unfortunately the plugin does not load in processing as it throws an error:
" NameError: name 'standard_library' is not defined"

```
 File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithmProvider.py", line 126, in loadAlgorithms
              alg = ScriptUtils.loadAlgorithm(moduleName, filePath)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptUtils.py", line 65, in loadAlgorithm
              spec.loader.exec_module(module)
              File "", line 855, in exec_module
              File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
              File "C:\work\[PLUGINNAME]\plugin_upload.py", line 13, in 
              standard_library.install_aliases()
             NameError: name 'standard_library' is not defined
```

If I rename the plugin_upload.py to a simple txt file, everything is working fine in QGIS.
Are there any "workarounds" to get this to work properly?!

Comment: Did you check if future is installed? For example in the OSGEO4W-Shell: 
pip show future